# How to style diffrent Collor Coulmn in Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/9y6sb/) and let me know how I can set diffrent color foe each of Columns in the chart?

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2014'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_proper_by_population">Wikipedia</a>'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                labels: {

                    align: 'center',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Population (millions)'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: 'Population in 2008: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>',
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Population',
                data: [
                    ['Shanghai', 23.7],
                    ['Lagos', 16,1],
                    ['Instanbul', 14.2],

                ],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    rotation: 0,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'center',
                    x: 5,
                    y: 25,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '14px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    });
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this two different ways. First you can explicitly give each point its own color which also involves explicitly keying each other value in the `data` element (`name`, `y`, etc):

```
        data: [
            {name: 'Shanghai', color: 'red', y: 23.7},
            {name: 'Lagos', color: 'blue', y: 16.1},
            {name: 'Instanbul', color: 'green', y:14.2}        
        ]
```

Secondly you can specify it with a parameter that depends on the Highcharts color array. Use the [`colorByPoint`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.colorByPoint) series attribute that is available for `bar` and `column` types (at least):

```
...
name: 'P2',
colorByPoint: true,
data: ...
```

Live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9y6sb/1/).

Comment: I keep saying it, but I really recommend highchart's API documentation. Tons of live examples. Some of this stuff is not fully supported so not in the API docs but you can inspect the highcharts object to see what is exposed. Pretty nifty stuff.